# XElementObj.Root.Element("anything") is always null for an XSL document

Tags: .net, xml

All was well with my code in the tracer-bullet version that used POX, but then I added the XSL and I can no longer use `.Element("anything")`

Here's my xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="*|@*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*" />
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="CO">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
   </head>
   <body></body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This throws a null reference exception:

```
templateDoc.Root.Element("body").Add(newElements);
```

because `.Element("body")` is null.  templateDoc is an XDocument object that has been properly loaded with the XML above using: `XDocument.Load(filePath);`

What do I need to do in order to be able to do find the body node here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify namespace.

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
  XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";

  var result = from ele in doc.Descendants(ns + "stylesheet").Descendants("html")
                select ele;
```

OR

```
    var result = (from ele in doc.Descendants(ns + "stylesheet").Descendants("body")
                 select ele).FirstOrDefault();

    if (result != null)
    {

        result.Add(new XElement("p", "Hello World"));
        doc.Save(file);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much AVD!   I was looking for a namespace property off of the XDocument object - didn't understand the the class heirarchy.  This is very helpful.